# syntax error, unexpected identifier "backend", expecting ")"when using blade syntax in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use the ternary operator using blade to print out the **active** class for an `<li>` tag by checking the name of the current route using the code below

```
<li class="nav-item {{ Route::currentRouteName() == 'backend.categories' ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

However, this doesn't work and i am presented with a ParseError which says

```
syntax error, unexpected identifier "backend", expecting ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information to understand what's going on.

From what I can see, the error is not on the line that you copied. Maybe try to search in the controller or in the routes file to see if there is some syntax error.

Tip: you can use [Blade conditional classes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#conditional-classes) to have a cleaner view.

Answer (score -1):

Instead use `$request->route()->getName()` ...and consider the Laravel version.

Comment: if you could please be lay more emphasis on your answer